# Add userAdmin in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

How to add a user with [userAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) role in Atlas?

The Cluster Security "Add New User" UI https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/.....#clusters/security/users shows only limited set of built-in roles without any option to enter role name manually:

[image]

So I am a bit stuck here - there are no options in the UI, and non of the existing roles allow to add users in a shell.

None of the roles in the list have `userAdmin` privilege.

The most "powerful" [atlasAdmin](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#atlas-user-privileges) assigned to a user on Create Cluster page covers only:

- readWriteAnyDatabase
- readAnyDatabase
- enableSharding
- dbAdminAnyDatabase
- clusterMonitor

and doesn't have enough privilege to execute `db.createUser()` command in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot grant this role. The **only** way to create new MongoDB users in Atlas is either via the UI or the API. See [Add MongoDB Users](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/) for details and note that this page states:

> Atlas rolls back any user modifications not made through the UI or API. You must use the Atlas UI or API to add, modify, or delete MongoDB users on Atlas clusters.

See [Create a Database User](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/database-users-create-a-user/) for details on how to create MongoDB users via the API.